# How to make a sheet or form in google to auto create a new sheet TAB?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a form where I want it to report to the same sheet but create a new tab at the beginning of each month. So lets say on Feb 1st the data collected in the form would create a new sheet TAB i.e.; Feb2021, Jan2021. etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by creating Installable Trigger.

**How to create Installable Trigger?**

> - Open your Apps Script project.
> - At the left, click Triggers alarm.
> - At the bottom right, click Add Trigger.
> - Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create. For this case, Click the drop down menu below **Select event type** and select **On form submit**
> - Click Save.

Your trigger should look like this:

[image]

### Try this:

**Code:**

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var timeStamp = e.namedValues['Timestamp'][0].split(" ");
  var date = new Date(timeStamp[0]);
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
  ];
  var dateName = months[month]+year;
  
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(dateName);
  //Create new sheet if sheet does not exists.
  if(!sheet) {
    sheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
    sheet.setName(dateName);
    //append column header
    var responseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
    sheet.appendRow(responseSheet.getRange(1,1,1,2).getValues()[0]);
  }
  //insert data to new sheet
  sheet.appendRow(e.values);
}
```

### Example

**Form:**

[image: Form]

**Response:**

[image: Responses]

**Output:**

[image: Output]

References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)
- [insertSheet(sheetName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname)

Comment: Yes, just change the number of column in `sheet.appendRow(responseSheet.getRange(1,1,1,2).getValues()[0])` based on the number of column in your Response sheet.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to coding. Would this interfere with a current App Script?

Comment: You could create a separate function and apply the code above to catch the event from submitting form.

Comment: Only the function you specified during the creation of Installable Trigger will get executed when an event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Where should I add it to this code?

```
var ssID = "1vW1wDYxib4JZ8X0pt_x0Ao6mXj6w9EQB18Q4JCkEWpo";
var formID = "1slxnQcgSEhIjF38d8ITcqQBchGjEQhEUw1Q9-ZCXT_Q";


var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("data");
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

function main(){
  var labels = wsData.getRange(1, 1,1,wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  
  labels.forEach(function(label,i){
   
    var options = wsData
                  .getRange(2, i + 1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1)
                  .getValues()
                  .map(function(o){ return o[0] });
    updateDropDownUsingTitle(label,options)
    
    
  });
  
}

function updateDropDownUsingTitle(title,values) {
  
  
  var items = form.getItems();
  var titles = items.map(function(item){
    return item.getTitle();
  });
  
  var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
  var item = items[pos];
  var itemID = item.getId();
  
  
  updateDropdown(itemID,values);
}


function updateDropdown(id, values) {
  
  var item = form.getItemById(id);
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);

}
```